# ActionBar Back Arrow/Button not appearing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I am switching between my fragments using:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[pos]));
tx.addToBackStack("tag");
tx.commit();
```

But when I do switch fragments, the back button or left caret is not appearing on my action bar. I have set

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

on the main activity but still doesnt work.

Am I placing the 2 previous lines of code in the wrong place or class? Or is it my navigation from fragment to another fragment that is not showing the left arrow/caret?

Answer (score 6):

What do you use for ActionBar ?

If you use ActionBarSherlock your activity should be like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    //CODE
}
```

If you use AppCompat from Google your activity should be like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //CODE
}
```

in your activity for enabling home button you should use :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: where does op mention about actionbarsherlock?

Comment: How do I get extends ActionBarActivity? My class already uses FragmentActivity

Comment: If you use AppCompat from google you has ActionBarActivity, And inside ActionBarActivity activity you can do getSupportFragmentManager() so you do not need use FragmentActivity.